# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Aviation breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 10         15
Users destroyed                                  85          0
Users deleted                                     9          0
Users contacted                                  22          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           163      2,260
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               79        747
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         18      4,220
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              319        582
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 4      2,597
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                1      4,968
Tags merged                                       9          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             5          3
Tag synonyms created                              7          0
Questions unprotected                             0          2
Questions reopened                               69         28
Questions protected                              16         69
Questions migrated                               15          0
Questions flagged⁴                               12        710
Questions closed                                120        978
Question flags handled⁴                         196        526
Posts unlocked                                    2          2
Posts undeleted                                  12         54
Posts locked                                      1        115
Posts deleted⁵                                  358      1,607
Posts bumped                                      0        419
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               48          0
Comments flagged                                 15      1,036
Comments deleted⁶                             2,401      2,965
Comment flags handled                           828        223
Answers flagged                                 252      2,710
Answer flags handled                          1,092      1,870
All comments on a post moved to chat             34          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Footnote 2 doesn't describe the "initial" suspension.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to you [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=accounts), and thanks to our community.

I want to highlight one part from the stats mentioned above:

> ```
> Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           163      2,260
> Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               79        747
> Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         18      4,220
> Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              319        582
> Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 4      2,597
> Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                1      4,968
> ```

Our aviation community reviewed 15,374 tasks, as opposed to 584 done by the moderators. This means that moderators only reviewed 3.7% of the tasks and rest were handled by the community.

I am elated to be part of such vibrant community. I love this forum more than any other SE forum, because:

- we are, *generally speaking*, much more welcoming to new users, and genuinely help them to improve their posts.
- we have great friendship between us, and many members know each other more than just a screen name.

Comment: Yeah, community moderation is a good news story here.