# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Aviation over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 11         15
Users destroyed³                                 71          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                  18          0
User banned from review                           4          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue           152      2,804
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue               92        932
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         69      5,270
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue               41        882
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                 8      2,687
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue               26      5,032
Tags merged                                       2          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             5          0
Tag synonyms created                              6          0
Questions unprotected                             2          1
Questions reopened                               75         36
Questions protected                              16         75
Questions migrated                               23          0
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁵                               11        762
Questions closed                                169        978
Question flags handled⁵                         227        547
Posts unlocked                                    1          9
Posts undeleted                                   8         50
Posts locked                                      6         86
Posts deleted⁶                                  452      1,465
Posts bumped                                      0        430
Comments undeleted                               36          0
Comments flagged                                  9        768
Comments deleted⁷                             2,499      2,851
Comment flags handled                           688         95
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                 190      3,016
Answer flags handled                          1,182      2,037
All comments on a post moved to chat             32          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: I will miss you Shog9. Although we haven't actively communicated here on Aviation.stackexchange, your contributions to the network and it's community did not go unnoticed. During the past few months, your examplary conduct during the Monica crisis gave hope that eventually Stack.Inc would find itself on the right track again; if it wasn't going to listen to the community, surely the voice of reason from within would be able to change the tide.It saddens me deeply that you and Robert are no longer with Stack Inc. Thank you for what you have done for the community. Thank you.